# Getting empty Array from WebAPI and SQL Server in AngularJS

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ef-model-first

In my project I'm getting an empty array from database. I'm using SQL Server, WebAPI 2 and for the client side AngularJS to display the data from the database. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is the client side code:

```
$http.get('/api/group')
  .success(function (data, status) {
     $log.info('Data:', data);
     $log.info('Status:', status);
  })
  .error(function (data, status) {
     $log.info('Data:', data);
     $log.info('Status:', status);
  });
```

WebAPI Controller of group:

```
public class GroupController : ApiController
{
  public EtfContext db = new EtfContext();

  // GET api/group
  public IQueryable<Group> GetGroups()
  {
    //var groups = from g in db.QR_Groups
    //             select g;
    //return groups;
    return db.QR_Groups;
  }
```

The Model of group:

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

And the DataContext for connecting to the database:

```
public class EfContext : DbContext
{
  public EfContext() 
    : base("name=EfContext")
    {
    }

  public DbSet<Group> QR_Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The Table  in the database called "QR_Groups" with 3 columns: id, name, code.
How do I get the data from the database?

Comment: Are there actual rows in the database?

Comment: change it to `return db.QR_Groups.ToList()` and make sure you have data in your database.

Comment: @Knelis Yes data is already in the database table.

Comment: @dotctor I'm using IQueryable. When I try to set `ToList` then I'm getting an error

Comment: Also change the return type of `GetGroups` to `IEnumerable<Group>`

Comment: @dotctor I've tried your solution but I'm still getting an empty array.

Comment: @yuro what error are you getting when you convert `ToList()`?

Comment: @Oluwafemi I'm getting an empty Array when I'm starting the WebAPI and type the path in the browser http://localhost:63831/api/group

Comment: @Oluwafemi in the console I'm getting the status 200

Comment: @Oluwafemi I'm getting the status 404.. Not found.